# If the graph of anti derivative of $f(x)$ passes through a point then the term independent of x in anti derivative is?

Tags: integration

If the graph of anti derivative of $f(x)$ passes through a point then the term independent of x in anti derivative is?
$$f(x)=\log(\log x)+\log^{-2}x,Point:(e,1998-e)$$
Trying to integrate $f(x)$:
$$I=\int (\log(\log x)+\log^{-2}x )dx$$
Let $t=\log x, x=e^t, dx=e^tdt$:
$$I=\int e^t(\log t+t^{-2})dt$$
But I was thinking of the form $\int e^x(g(x)+g'(x))dx=e^xg(x)$, but $(\log t)'=t^{-1}\ne t^{-2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry suddenly I realized that we can write:
$$I=\int e^t(\log t+t^{-1}-t^{-1}+t^{-2})dt=\int e^t(\log t+t^{-1})dt+\int e^t(-t^{-1}+t^{-2})dt=e^t(\log t-t^{-1})+c=x(\log(\log x)-\log^{-1}x)+c$$
Now $1998-e=e(\log(\log e)-\log^{-1}e)+c=c-e\implies c=1998$
So answer is $1998$